# maven doesn't resolve profile's property on a classifier of transitive dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-3

I 'm trying to use classifier on a multimodule project which looks like

root project
--ejb
--jar
--servlet
--ear

The ejb project depends of jar project
The war project depends of ejb project and by a transitive way depends of jar project

Unfortunately, on my servlet project, the classifier of the jar project is never resolved

I also defined a profile

```
 <profile>
  <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
      <maven.deployment.suffix>dev</maven.deployment.suffix>       
      <envClassifier>dev</envClassifier>
      <exploded>true</exploded>
       ...
    </properties>
 </profile>
```

When I try to package the project with this profile and artifacts classified I always have the following error :

> `mvn -P dev clean install`
>   ...
>   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project servlet: Could not resolve dependencies for > > project root.project.servlets:servlet:war:1.0: Could not transfer artifact root.project.projects:logging:jar:${env
>   Classifier}:1.0 from/to nexus (http://.../nexus/content/groups/public): > IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 102: .../nexus> /content/groups/public/root/project/projects/logging/1.0/logging-1.0-${envClassifier}.jar -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR] ...

I [uploaded a sample to bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/littlewing/bugreporting/src)

I tried to do the following command on my servlet project

> $ mvn -P dev help:effective-pom

I saw that the classifier is well resolved. But it's not applied to transitive dependencies.

The only workaround is to inject the property on the startup of maven as `-DenvClassifier=dev`

Finally, I saw [few issues on jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-1388) but not resolved 
How can I solve this problem ? I guess I'm not the only guy on earth to use maven with classifier on multimodule projects...

Comment: You know the concept of -SNAPSHOT ?

Comment: Yes I do,could you explain how the snapshot release can solve my problem ?

Comment: It looks you are trying to use the classifier for the distinction between development and usual release. This is the intention of SNAPSHOT releases for which you don't need a classifier. And in particular based on the code i've taken a look into. Furthermore you don't follow best practices for multi-module builds (no defining versions in artifact etc.). Also it's weird to define all dependencies in a dependencyManagement block in the root pom. May be you can elaborate a little bit more what exactly you like to achieve? in particular for what you like to use the classifiers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven: Depending on inheriting artifact causes build error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171222/maven-depending-on-inheriting-artifact-causes-build-error)