# Deploying multiple SNAPSHOT artifacts into the same repository in Sonatype OSSRH

Tags: maven, native, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I've seen [Building and deploying native code using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40853862/building-and-deploying-native-code-using-maven) - but can't get this (very similar) deployment working as I'd like..

I have a C++ project that builds with Maven, and the Maven CMake Plugin. This involves several Maven profiles, to select the correct settings for the various C++ compilers I use on the platforms I'm building on. (Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 18.04, CentOS 7, Raspbian, macOS High Sierra). I use Jenkins to run this build on the various VMs/Raspberry Pi - yielding a .tar.gz or .zip via the Maven Assembly Plugin. The final result is six archive files, that vary in their classifier/type. They all have the same groupId/artifactId.

I wanted each of these jobs to deploy its archive to Sonatype's OSSRH Nexus system, using the nexus-staging-maven-plugin.

I had this plugin configured to not automatically close the repository, so that the multiple builds could run via Jenkins (sequentially), and deploy to the same repo. I would then review this in the web UI, then Release or Drop it appropriately.

This worked fine, when the project had a version number of 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. However, when I decided to (manually) release this, by setting the version to 0.0.1, and run my Jenkins builds... the deployment behaviour was different to what I'd seen when it was a SNAPSHOT.

Each platform-specific deployment created its own staging repository in the OSSRH Snapshots repo.

After reading https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-maven-plugins/tree/master/staging/maven-plugin, I have tried a variety of these settings, but nothing seems to work:

```
<skipStagingRepositoryClose>true</skipStagingRepositoryClose>
<skipStaging>true</skipStaging>
<autoReleaseAfterClose>false</autoReleaseAfterClose>
<stagingRepositoryId>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-repo</stagingRepositoryId>
```

The nexus-staging:rc-open goal looks like it might help, allowing me to open a named staging repository (as I tried to do with stagingRepositoryId, above) - but it requires a staging profile id - I've used the rc-list-profiles goal to find mine - but when I give this to rc-open, it's reported as "missing or invalid".

It looks like this should be possible: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-maven-plugins/blob/master/staging/maven-plugin/WORKFLOWS.md - this suggests that you can't create a new staging profile id; that they're allocated by Nexus.

Why is this mechanism different between SNAPSHOT and non-SNAPSHOT deployments?

Kind regards, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated https://stackoverflow.com/a/40954957/14731. Per point 6.6, SNAPSHOTs cannot be released atomically. There is no known workaround.